# Please review proxy re-signature on Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, bls-signature

I want to implement proxy re-signature on elliptic curve.

I've been thinking about ideas like the one below, but are there any problems?

Key Generate:

- $a = $ alice's secret key
- $aG$ = alice's public key
- $b = $ bob's secret key
- $bG = $bob's secret key
- $rk_{ab} = aP * b^{-1} = a/bG$

First Sign:

- $Pm$ is hashed point
- $k = $ random
- $r = ka^{-1}$
- $z = e(G, G)$
- $s = z^kPm$

Resign:

- $r' = rk_{ab} * r = a/bP * ka^{-1} = k*1/b*G$
- $s' = s$

Verification:

- $t = e(bG, r) = e(G, G)^k = z^k$
- Check $tPm == s'$

Comment: Reviewing full scheme design is off-topic for this site. But you may break down specific components of the formula, and assumptions to make it on-topic. And the best way to get this started, I think, would be to annotate each step of your scheme with comments that explains what they achieves, both mathematically and security-wise/logically.

Comment: e(aG, r) = z^k, So Anyone can generate a new signature via z^k .